# Java JoptionsPane button strings

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I wonder if there is a way to change the default joptions pane buttons strings instead of say "ok" and "cancel" to say something other like "option1" and "option2".
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that...Have a look here....

```
String[] options = new String[] {"op1", "op2", "op3"};
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Options", "Hi there", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) -

```
Object[] options = { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Click OK to continue", "My Title",

        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,

        null, options, options[0]);
```

The above code -

> Show a warning dialog with the options *Option 1*, *Option 2*, *Option 3*, title *My Title*, and message *Click OK to continue*.

For more information, you can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial.

Comment: Can I do it with OK_CANCEL_OPTION?

Comment: @Vagelism: Just try it. I think you should be able to do it. Just change the option to `JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION`.

Comment: Thank you! I go write now to check it!

Comment: @Vagelism: You should be able to configure each portion, like you should be able to change `JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION` to `JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION`, `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE` to `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`....

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
String[] choices = { "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4" };
int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Dialog text",
            "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, choices, null);
System.out.println(response);
```

It returns `0-3` (chosen option) or `-1` if you cancel the dialog.

Comment: Yes work great, but I have a showinput dialog and want to change not only the buttons strings but also to take the value of the input.